# What is recommended - keeping empty lists/arrays versus Null in spark tables?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

I have a large spark table containing mixed data types String,arrays,maps
The array and map columns are sparse in nature. Should i keep empty arrays in values for these columns or make them null?
Similarly is it recommended to use empty strings "" for storing or null?
What is a good practice and advantages and disadvantages of both?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking I would always try to use `NULL` values instead of empty strings or arrays. The main reason for me for me his how they are handled in spark, e.g. when joining two data frames. `NULL` values are ignored in joins, but empty strings or lists are not. This can often result in very skew data, which can heavily slow down your transformations. Some information about skew data can be found [here [external link]](https://itnext.io/handling-data-skew-in-apache-spark-9f56343e58e8).

In addition, `NULL` values are also often ignored in functions like `coalesce` of columns [[docs]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce), `count` in aggregations [[related question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306076/count-including-null-in-pyspark-dataframe-aggregation) or `first(col, ignorenulls=True)` [[docs]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg#pyspark.sql.functions.first). If you want to use the functions as they are intended, I would also recommend using `NULL` over empty string/list.

To sum this up: using `NULL` over other values like empty strings or lists, allows you to profit for more native Spark functionality and I would recommend to use `NULL` when ever possible.